# What to call the mean between Buy price and Sell price?

Tags: terminology, finance

In currency exchange (for example when you have US dollars and want to buy euros, or the opposite), what do you call the mean between the Buy price and Sell price?

In Japanese we call it *TTM*:

> TTM = (TTB + TTS) /2

Where *TTB* is the price at which you can buy cash, and *TTS* the price at which you can sell cash.

Is there a similar word or abbreviation in English?

Answer (score 4):

I think [*mid price*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid_price), a short form of the more obvious [*mid-market price*](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/mid-market-price.html) is what you are looking for (though the linked articles mainly refer to stocks).  I have certainly heard and used mid-market price for this.

Comment: Side note, do not get it confused with `half price` or `half market price` as this means 50% less (money).